# Merging two blend files with animations

Tags: animation

I have two blend files which both have animations. 
Could someone explain how i merge this files? Also will I lose anything?
Thank you

Comment: You add little details, but I guess each file has at least an object animated. Open file A, then use file>append (or use shift-f1) then select the file B: now you must select at least one element from this other file: eg select an object that has animation in file B, then confirm. Now your file A has both objects and each has its own animation. You can also use a completely new file and append animated objects from both A and B (thus you preserve them as they are).

Comment: Thank you, please answer so i can give you the correct answer.